# Avoid model duplicates in Spring-boot for different dataSources

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, model-view-controller

I'm using Spring-Boot with Kotlin and try to save a "Student" object into 2 different databases. (PostgreSQL and Redis)
To achieve this I created 2 Student models, because Postgres and Redis need different annotations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
data class StudentPostgres(
    @Id var id: Int? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var gender: Gender? = null,
    var grade: Int? = null
) {
    enum class Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }
}

@RedisHash("Student")
data class StudentRedis(@Id var id: String? = null, var name: String, var gender: Gender, var 
grade: Int) {

    enum class Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }
}
```

I also had to create 2 repositories.

```
@Repository
interface StudentPostgresRepository: JpaRepository<StudentPostgres, String>

@Repository
interface StudentRedisRepository: JpaRepository<StudentRedis, String>
```

My code works and data gets saved in both DBs but as you can see above I have a lot of redundant code.

```
val studentPostgres = StudentPostgres(1, "John Doe", StudentPostgres.Gender.MALE, 1)
val studentRedis = StudentRedis("001", "John Doe", StudentRedis.Gender.MALE, 1)

studentRedisRepository.save(studentRedis)
studentPostgresRepository.save(studentPostgres)
```

Is there a better way to avoid these duplicates and still save students into both databases?

Comment: Put both annotations on 1 model... Why would a model only be able to use a single annotation? Depending on what you use it for there might be better ways of integration both technologies.

Comment: @M.Deinum Doesn't work. When I use these annotations in one model it always gets written into Redis but never in Postgres.

\@RedisHash("Student")
\@Entity
\@Table(name = "student")

Comment: I said 1 model, you still need 2 repositories and some explicit configuration for both. But if you need/want to sync them there are probably better ways to integrate this on either the hibernate or database level.